# Is permgen included in -Xmx?

Tags: java, permgen

When I say `-Xmx=1024m`, does this include permgen i.e `-XX:MaxPermSize=` is taken from these 1024m or it is separate?

Looking at [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/)
I thought that it takes from 1024m, but until now I had believed they were separate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, permGen space is in addition to main heap (latter capped via -Xmx on Sun VMs)

Answer (score 7):

Permanent generation is a separate space allocated via `-XX:MaxPermSize=`. This is in addition to the heap set with `-Xmx`.

See the diagram at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc1-4-2-135950.html#3.%20Sizing%20the%20Generations|outline "3. Sizing the Generations"

This shows the "Total Size" i.e. `Xmx` does not count the Permanent generation.

And by the way, JDK 1.4 is quite old. Check the JDK 1.6 options and links for an updated view: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html