# Java heap Xmx flag and max size of diff spaces of my app in prod

Tags: java, heap-memory

a) As I know `-Xmx` represents max heap.
Is it a combination of young generation(eden+survivor) and tenured generation(old generation) and perm gen ?

b) How can I now the **min/max size** of different spaces of memory of the application which is in UAT/Prod
1) eden space
2) survior space
3) tenured
4) perm gen

Answer (score 2):

You can watch these sizes externally using jstat like

```
jstat -gc {pid} 10s
```

You can find out the pid by using

```
jps -lvm
```

Comment: i mean the command jstat -gc {pid} 10s, second one is running fine

Comment: @Naroji Have you replaced `{pid}` with the process id found using jps?

Comment: yup, that much i understand :) , but not sure where i m missing

Answer (score 1):

Perm generation is a separate space allocated via `MaxPermSize`. This is not included in `-Xmx`

`-Xmx` includes one Eden space , two survivor space and old generation.

You can even calculate the individual spaces by knowing `--xx:NewRation:`. This is ratio between the young and old generations. For example if `n` is `3` than ratio is `1:3` and the combined size of `Eden` and `survivor` spaces is **`one forth`** of the total size of the young and old generation.

You can also use **`jstat`** command to know individual sizes and also tools like **VisualVM** can help you great deal. Just look in to the picture which states you pictorial representation of individual space details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the size of those space use the java option `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails`.
This [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) will help you understand how the differents generations work.

Answer (score 0):

The max heap size allocated via `-Xmx` is a combination of the young generation and the tenured generation. permgen space is allocated separately, using the `-XX:MaxPermSize` option to the JVM. This question is answered here:

[Is permgen included in -Xmx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084280/is-permgen-included-in-xmx)

One good way to determine the sizing of the different generations in the heap in a JVM - particularly on a remote server - is to use the jmap command:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html

Here's some sample output from a server that I administer:

```
$ sudo jmap -heap 28579

Attaching to process ID 28579, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 1.5.0_07-b03

using parallel threads in the new generation.
using thread-local object allocation.
Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 6127878144 (5844.0MB)
   NewSize          = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   OldSize          = 3980394496 (3796.0MB)
   NewRatio         = 15
   SurvivorRatio    = 1024
   PermSize         = 314572800 (300.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 314572800 (300.0MB)

Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 2145452032 (2046.0625MB)
   used     = 2130014864 (2031.3404693603516MB)
   free     = 15437168 (14.722030639648438MB)
   99.28047014010332% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 2143420416 (2044.125MB)
   used     = 2130014864 (2031.3404693603516MB)
   free     = 13405552 (12.784530639648438MB)
   99.37457197384462% used
From Space:
   capacity = 2031616 (1.9375MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 2031616 (1.9375MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 2031616 (1.9375MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 2031616 (1.9375MB)
   0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 3980394496 (3796.0MB)
```