# how to increase maven PermGen space

Tags: maven, java-7

I get this error doing my build:

```
[ERROR] PermGen space -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
```

with java 7.  Help?

Comment: You are facing this during a normal build ?

Comment: Yeah.  Not sure at which exact phase...

Comment: Large build? On which JDK and which Maven version are you running...Are running your build inside a container etc. ? Plain command line?

Comment: command line, JDK 7, maven 3.6.  Yeah large build :)

Comment: Can you give a number what you mean by large build cause I had builds with 800+ modules in a single build where I didn't had the need for this? Or do you tests causing that? Unit or integration tests?

Comment: Something like that I have expected. Pulling a dependency will only be done once and should not influence tests except the tests are integration tests ?

Comment: Running with `maven install -DskipTests` it doesn't fail so I assume it's running out of Perm Gen doing the unit tests.  Or something like that? This particular case is very weird, it actually runs out of Perm Gen "once" (the "first time") then after that it works OK. It's possible it pulls in some very large 3rd party dependencies or something like that, I don't understand the project well.

Comment: Yeah could be IT or some plugin...

Comment: Pulling is unrelated I suppose but without the full logoutput it's hard to guess. Check also via `mvn clean verify -DskipTests` and the output is important ...furthermore Do you have configured some memory settings in you environment? MAVEN_OPTS etc.? Running from plain command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do it (the MaxPermSize [part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084280/is-permgen-included-in-xmx)):

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m"`

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError

There are also other ways to set it for a [specific project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998748/32453).

Apparently the concept of MaxPermSize was removed in java 8, FWIW.